# how to add footer in given in android

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00b9e8"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- <include layout="@layout/header" /> -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search Status"
            android:textColor="#0060a4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_15dp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/searchstatus_imgBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Status"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="8dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Accepted"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="40dip"
                android:layout_height="40dip"
                android:paddingLeft="25dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Reason"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearlayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.65"
            android:background="@drawable/round_bg"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reason"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#0060a4"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayot>
```

This is my code i want to add one Footer but i am unable to do this i dont know why this Problem is  coming  even i have take relative layout then also its not working please tell me how add one footer  plz Help

Comment: That's not code, is a layout.

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method and better to use relative layout for this.[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#999"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FOOTER"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:background="#666"
            />

        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this will give like this .is that you want ?

[image]

Comment: But my  contrl not coming Properly

Comment: Can you Please post your expected design